# Kotlin class properties in parathesis and curly parathesis

Tags: kotlin

Just reading some Kotlin code and notice that we can define properties either in `(...)` or in `{...}`.

```
class Foo(val name: String = "Yuchen") {
    val name2: String = "Zhong"
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val foo = Foo()
    println(foo.name)
    println(foo.name2)
}
```

What're their differences and when should we use which?

Comment: Read it here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you transform **kotlin** code to **java** using bytecode decompiler you will get that one.

```
class InitOrderDemo(val name: String = "Yuchen") {
    val name2: String = "Zhong"
}
```

Decompiled java code:

```
public final class InitOrderDemo {
   @NotNull
   private final String name2;
   @NotNull
   private final String name;

   @NotNull
   public final String getName2() {
      return this.name2;
   }

   @NotNull
   public final String getName() {
      return this.name;
   }

   public InitOrderDemo(@NotNull String name) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(name, "name");
      super();
      this.name = name;
      this.name2 = "Zhong";
   }
   ....
}
```

Notice, please, that `name` argument you can pass through constructor invoke, but `name2` couldn't be changed - it's similar to constant here.

So if you want property to be immutable (but not constant for all instances of that class), you will need define it in `()` - in constructor.